# Codeception - empty coverage in second level deep folders

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage, codeception

I'm using codeception along with a Phalcon framework project.

My structure is :

```
app/
     business/
          pro/
              PricingManager.php
     ProductManager.php
```

/!\ Codeception coverage never seems to achieve the pro directory.

```
coverage:
    enabled: true
    include:
        - app/*
    exclude:
        - app/cache/*
```

The result is :

```
\Business::Business\ProductManager
  Methods: 100.00% ( 6/ 6)   Lines: 100.00% ( 22/ 22)
```

I even tried with

```
   include:
        - app/business/pro/*
```

In that case, no coverage at all.

PricingManager is never covered. PricingManager's namespace is Business\Pro, but I don't think this is the problem.

If I move it to business folder, everything is working just fine. But the problem keeps on happening everywhere in my project anyway (ex : models/ folder is covered but not models/accouting/*, models/repositories/*, etc)

Thanks for your help.

FYI, the command I run :

```
codecept run unit --env dev-unit managers/ --coverage
```

Comment: Perhaps the whitelist/blacklist syntax described at https://codeception.com/docs-1.8/11-Codecoverage#Configuration works? I vaguely recall problems with the default include/exclude and using whitelist/blacklist works for me. Making the namespace match is probably a good idea too though - Codeception uses the namespace and not the path when telling you what test it is running.

Comment: I think I tried it already. I just tried it again and I don't see any changes. Thanks for the help. Fortunately, sonar-scanner gives a real coverage and includes all the files in the projects. It's just a pity to have to launch a scan as well as codeception's builtin coverage feature.